# Disabling send button for empty input

Tags: javascript, jquery

In designing a chat app i have text area and button in a form. To disable send button for empty textarea i did below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn1').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#msg').keyup(function(){
        $('#btn1').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);    
    })
});
```

Above code is disabling send button for initial blank space as well which i want to restrict (remember in textarea "   hai" is fine but "(all blank spaces)" is not fine)

Comment: Try `$('#btn1').prop('disabled', !this.value.trim())`

Comment: no @elclanrs its enabling send button always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#msg').keyup(function(){
    var msg = this.value.trim(); // remove left and right blank spaces.
    $('#btn1').prop('disabled', msg == "" ? true : false);    
});
```

Just remove TOL and EOL blank spaces. If no `trim` method, implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#msg').keyup(function(){
  var msg = $.trim($(this).val()); // remove left and right blank spaces.
  $('#btn1').prop('disabled', msg == "" ? true : false);    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 $('#btn1').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#msg').keyup(function() {
        $('#btn1').prop('disabled', $.trim(this.value) === "" ? true : false);
    });
```